# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting this huge error running a Mocha test with node version 10 and a MongoDB database:

> (node:27884) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError
>   [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:
>
> assert(
>       user.blogPosts[0].comments[0].content ===
>         'As programs get bigger, they also become more complex'   )
>
> ```
> at User.findOne.populate.then.user (/Users/danale/Projects/users/test/association_test.js:50:9)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) (node:27884) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> ```
>
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:27884) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

For a Mocha test that was working earlier:

```
it('saves a full relation graph', done => {
    User.findOne({ name: 'Joe' })
      .populate({
        path: 'blogPosts',
        populate: {
          path: 'comments',
          model: 'comment',
          populate: {
            path: 'user',
            model: 'user'
          }
        }
      })
      .then(user => {
        assert(user.name === 'Joe');
        assert(user.blogPosts[0].title === 'Eloquent JavaScript');
        assert(
          user.blogPosts[0].comments[0].content ===
            'As programs get bigger, they also become more complex'
        );
        assert(user.blogPosts[0].comments[0].user.name === 'Joe');
        done();
      });
  });
```

So I know the issue is here:

```
assert(
   user.blogPosts[0].comments[0].content ===
     'As programs get bigger, they also become more complex'
);
```

but what exactly is wrong with this?

Comment: why not add a catch block with a console and or a debug point to figure out what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message was appropriate for the `content` I was testing because I was testing the wrong `content` in the `it()` block. I was testing the `content` inside my `beforeEach()`:

```
beforeEach(done => {
    joe = new User({ name: 'Joe' });
    blogPost = new BlogPost({
      title: 'Eloquent JavaScript',
      content: 'As programs get bigger, they also become more complex'
    });
```

When I was really trying to test the `content` in the `comment` object here:
`comment = new Comment({ content: 'Love this post' });`

Once I corrected this to the appropriate `content` above, all tests are passing.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `catch` block to find out. populate() returns a promise, but when promises fail, they need to be caught and handled.

See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) for more info, but think of it like a `try { } catch { }` block which you might already be familiar with.

Here your code is appended with catch, and a log of the error that occurred.

```
it('saves a full relation graph', done => {
User.findOne({ name: 'Joe' })
  .populate({
    path: 'blogPosts',
    populate: {
      path: 'comments',
      model: 'comment',
      populate: {
        path: 'user',
        model: 'user'
      }
    }
  })
  .then(user => {
    assert(user.name === 'Joe');
    assert(user.blogPosts[0].title === 'Eloquent JavaScript');
    assert(
      user.blogPosts[0].comments[0].content ===
        'As programs get bigger, they also become more complex'
    );
    assert(user.blogPosts[0].comments[0].user.name === 'Joe');
    done();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Handling promise rejection", err);
  });
});
```

Comment: XaxD, I tried that and it did not work. So I reviewed my code some more and I noticed that my assertion was failing because I was referencing the wrong `content`. I was testing for this `blogPost = new BlogPost({
      title: 'Eloquent JavaScript',
      content: 'As programs get bigger, they also become more complex'
    });` instead of this: `comment = new Comment({ content: 'Love this post' });`